# Angular2 Module with private nested DI Context

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular2-modules

I am aware that Angular2 default DI Context strategy is to enrich an application-wide Dependency Injection Context. But I would like some `Injectables` to not be globally available.

Here is a concrete example of what I am trying to achieve.

There is probably a doc explaining how to do so but I have not been able to find it.

I would like to create a ServiceModule that would differentiate Public/Exported services from Private services.

```
@Injectable() export class PrivateService{} // Not available in AppModule
@Injectable() export class PubliclyExportedService{ // Available in AppModule
  constructor(private privateService: PrivateService) { }
}

// The imported module
@NgModule({
  exports: [PubliclyExportedService],
  declarations: [PubliclyExportedService],
  providers: [
    PubliclyExportedService,
    PrivateService
  ]
})
export class ServiceModule {}

// The main module
@NgModule({
  imports: [ServiceModule]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The goal is to use the dependency injection so that `PubliclyExportedService` can use `PrivateService` but any class outside of the `ServiceModule` would not be capable of injecting the `PrivateService`.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you tried to exclude PrivateService from Module and include it into @Component itself where you're using that service?

Comment: Whats the problem with this, other than declaring a service ?

Comment: @DDRamone I cannot do that because I want the private services to be injected so that they can be mocked. If I follow what you meant, you would have done in the `PubliclyExportedService` constructor a `new PrivateService()`. Am I correct?

Comment: @raj The problem is to be able to state what can be resolved from a module. Here with every service being part of the main DI Context you are no longer capable of restricting the access of your module.

Comment: @Linvi Your question is about putting that service as `public` or `private`. I suggested a way to keep services `private`. I should inject them via constructor anyway for both `private` or `public` services. (Term `private` isn't correct here, but you guess what i mean.

Comment: *btw*, you dont need to add `PubliclyExportedService` into `exports`. 
( https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/NgModule-interface.html#!#exports-anchor )

Comment: I do not think there is a way to do it as you wanted it to be injected into services.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your `private` provider (Service) into your every Component, that are using that service:

```
 @Component({
  ...
  providers: [
    MyPrivateService // <= Using provider into this class
  ]
})
export class FeatureComponent{

  constructor(private _service: MyPrivateSrvice) { }

}
```

This approach gives you ability not to declare Service as provider into your root module or shared module.

Comment: Good idea, I will try this out tonight and give you some feedback. Are you sure that `@Injectable` decorator have their own `providers` property? I am asking the question as I am not trying to create `@components` here but `@injectables`

Comment: @Linvi If it's not `@Component`, you're forced to add it into Module providers (But this makes it to be public for other components). There's no other way i think. I will try to find workaround and update u